# Retrofit2 - Send dynamic keys with duplicate keys

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I need to send dynamic keys with duplicate keys.

this is what i need:

```
https://myApi.com/pepole?name=yoni&name=albert&brand=nike
```

all the keys are dynamics (name, brand).

so to do it dynamically i used `@Querymap` for exmpale:

```
Map<String, String> parms = new HashMap<>();

parms.put(dynamicKey, dynamicValue);

parms.put(anotherDynamicKey,anotherDynamicValue);
```

and this is my interface:

```
@Get("pepole")
Call<List> searchPepole(
@Querymap Map<String, String> options);
```

and is working fine but my problem starts when i have duplicate keys.

so how can i make call with dynamic keys with duplicates keys?

Comment: I'm not aware of a solution with `QueryMap` because the underlying `Map<>` interface doesn't allow duplicate keys. However, you could utilize query parameters: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-multiple-query-parameters-of-same-name Those can be duplicated.

Comment: Didn't work with `Query("name") List<String> duplicateKeysQuery, @QueryMap Map<String, String> differentKeysQuery` ?